# Modify dimensions, background image etc... of Inno Wizard Pages

Tags: inno-setup

I have this part of code which adjusts my welcome page but the finished page is still default Inno page with the ugly wizardpicture on the side. I want to do the same thing to finished page as i did with welcome

```
[Code]
    procedure InheritBoundsRect(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
    begin
      ATarget.Left := 210;
      ATarget.Top := ASource.Top;
      ATarget.Width := 295;
      ATarget.Height := ASource.Height;
    end;

    procedure InitializeWizard;
    var
      TopWelcomeLabel: TLabel;
      BottomWelcomeLabel: TLabel;
    begin

      WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Align := alClient;
      WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('Q:\Inno\wizardimages\new\bmp.bmp');
      TopWelcomeLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
      TopWelcomeLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Parent;
      TopWelcomeLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Font;
      TopWelcomeLabel.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Caption;
      TopWelcomeLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.WordWrap;
      InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1, TopWelcomeLabel);
      WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Visible := False;

      BottomWelcomeLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
      BottomWelcomeLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Parent;
      BottomWelcomeLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font;
      BottomWelcomeLabel.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption;
      BottomWelcomeLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.WordWrap;
      InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2, BottomWelcomeLabel);
      WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Visible := False;
    end;
```

EDITED WITH SOLUTION:

And now with the help of the guy bellow this is the new code that seems to work great

```
[Code]
    procedure InheritBoundsRect(ASource, ATarget: TControl);
    begin
      ATarget.Left := 210;
      ATarget.Top := ASource.Top;
      ATarget.Width := 295;
      ATarget.Height := ASource.Height;
    end;

    procedure InitializeWizard;
    var
      TopWelcomeLabel: TLabel;
      BottomWelcomeLabel: TLabel;
    begin

      WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Align := alClient;
      WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('bmp.bmp');
      TopWelcomeLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
      TopWelcomeLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Parent;
      TopWelcomeLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Font;
      TopWelcomeLabel.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Caption;
      TopWelcomeLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.WordWrap;
      InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1, TopWelcomeLabel);
      WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Visible := False;
      BottomWelcomeLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
      BottomWelcomeLabel.Parent := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Parent;
      BottomWelcomeLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Font;
      BottomWelcomeLabel.Caption := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Caption;
      BottomWelcomeLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.WordWrap;
      InheritBoundsRect(WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2, BottomWelcomeLabel);
      WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.Visible := False;

      WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Align := alClient;


//Stackoverflow changes start here...

      WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('bmp.bmp');

      WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Left := 210;
      WizardForm.FinishedLabel.Width := 265;

      WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Left := 210;
      WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.Width := 265

      WizardForm.RunList.Left := 210;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component names from the final page are:

- FinishedLabel
- FinishedHeadingLabel
- WizardBitmapImage2

I've marked them in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, got it all done by adding .Width and .Left and now i just need to figure out the label for "Run ProgramName"? that appears n the bottom of the page because this one is still far on the left

Comment: I think you mean the `RunList`. Optionally, there's the `YesRadio` and `NoRadio` which are used for computer restart.